# Как избавится от sequence в postgresql 11 с помощью JPA?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Возможно ли добиться нормального [автоинкремента](https://habr.com/ru/post/339568/) для psql 11.x, чтобы на выходе был вот такой DDL, а не генерировало `sequence` с помощью JPA или Hibernate аннотаций:

```
CREATE TABLE usertest (
    id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar NOT NULL
);
```

*Entity:*

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "testsite", name = "usertest")
public class UserTest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
}
```

Для H2 и MySQL генерирует верно, а для psql создает sequence

Comment: Самая прогрессивная реализация JPA - это Hibernate, а самый свежий PostgreSQL, который поддерживает Hibernate - это 9.5. Так что в данный момент никак.

Comment: Да я видел что диалект остановился на 9.5, правда на github в пакете hibernate есть диалект для psql 10, уже 9 месяцев как

Comment: А какое тогда решение можете подсказать, проектировать БД самому, а hibernate говорить чтобы только валидировал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сегодня состоялся релиз [SpringBoot 2.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes) в котором обновили Hibernate, теперь есть нужный диалект, но его можно не указывать

> Hibernate Dialect
>   Spring Boot now lets Hibernate chose the dialect to use rather than applying a default dialect based on the detected database. If you had a dialect configured previously, you may want to remove your customization.